# Why does a single-quote cause an error in my application?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I got the vulnerable code below from a book about SQL injection. But when I try to exploit it and add `'` to the input, it gives me an error like this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

Why do I get this error?

```
// build dynamic SQL statement
$SQL = “SELECT ∗ FROM table WHERE field = ‘$_GET[“input”]’;”;
// execute sql statement
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
// check to see how many rows were returned from the database
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
// iterate through the record set returned
$row = 1;
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
if ($row <= $rowcount)
{
print $db_field[$row]. “<BR>”;
$row++;
}
}
```

Comment: Is it only when you add a `'`? Because you also have a syntax error...Notice the two `;` in your query

Comment: Though there likely is a SQL injection here, this is less a security question and more of a code review post.

Comment: @BubbleHacker No this is syntaxically correct. The first one is inside the sql request and the second one outside (ending the php declaration). 
Lee The problem is because you are not escaping user input. This is very dangerous and it is a critical vulnerability in your application, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @Xavier59 No...In PHP you do not do something like that. When you add a `;` it ends the line right there. The correct syntax would have been `...= ‘".$_GET['input']."’”;....`

Comment: @BubbleHacker `;` doesn't end a line, it ends an instruction. The first `;` is inside the SQL statement, between the brackets `"`. So it ends the SQL statement. The second one is ending the php instruction.

Comment: @xavier59 , yeah i saw this code from a book about sql-injection , so its right what you say .

Comment: @BubbleHacker As a matter of fact, here would be a working code (still SQLi).  `$SQL = “SELECT ∗ FROM table WHERE field = ‘{$_GET[“input”]}’;”;`
This is working in php7. For sure, there is not excedent `;` in the query, only maybe a syntax error depending of his php version.

Comment: You're using curly quotes for one thing `“ ”` - `‘ ’` which should be `"` and `'` respectively, given if that's your real code. And if it is, PHP's error reporting would have thrown you a parse error first. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whats up with your quotation characters, but lets look at this line of code instead:

```
$SQL = "SELECT ∗ FROM table WHERE field = '$_GET[input]';";
```

So lets say you want to exploit this and get all rows. If you set `$_GET[input] = "' OR 1=1"` you get the following SQL:

```
SELECT ∗ FROM table WHERE field = '' OR 1=1';"
```

This is invalid SQL. Why? Because at the end you have a stray `'` that the SQL interpreter doesn't understand. After a condition there is not suppose to be a beginning of a quote, and all quotes should be closed! That is why you get an error.

So to do succesful injection you need to make sure you produce valid SQL. In this case you could try using the payload `' OR '' = '`, that generates this:

```
SELECT ∗ FROM table WHERE field = '' OR '' = '';"
```

Or just use a comment, as in `' OR 1=1 --`, to neutralize the rest of the query:

```
SELECT ∗ FROM table WHERE field = '' OR 1=1 --';"
```

Comment: Sidenote: You might want to have a look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399625/why-does-a-single-quote-cause-an-error-in-my-application#comment70001136_41399625) I left under their question.